# What happens when there is an error in FlatFileFooterCallback?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have spring batch application which writes to a file using FlatFileItemWriter. There is a Footer call back for the above ItemWriter. When there is an exception from Footer callback it is not causing the Batch to fail. Batch is completing with a status of COMPLETED (successful).

Do you know why?

Comment: We will need more information.  What is the exception? Is it being eaten?

Answer (score 0):

In the exception handling in Footer callback how do you control the flow ? Do you throw and exception or just log it and continue ?

Also have you set to skip the exceptions thrown by the Footer Callback in the batch context like ,

Please add both the spring batch context and Footer callback class here.